# MYSQL using JOIN TYPE 'ALL' when checked in explain plan

Tags: mysql, explain

The query is as below,

```
select *
from lab this_ 
inner join visits v1_ on this_.visit_id=v1_.id
```

`v1_.id` is primary key in the query.

It takes more than 1 minute to complete.

Below is the plan.

```
id   select_type   table   type  possible_keys  key       
1      SIMPLE       v1_     ALL    <null>      <null>
1      SIMPLE      this_    ALL    <null>      <null>
```

Not sure why primary key is picked as key. Also type is ALL.

Comment: "primary key is picked as key" - where do you see that?

Answer (score 5):

Mysql may ignore an index during the excution of the query if it belives that the alternative plan is more efficient. A couple of points it considers:

1. The size of the tables. If the visits table is small, then there is not too much point in using the index.
2. Selectivity. You do join the 2 tables, however there is no filtering and you want all fields from both tables. This could mean that mysql has to return most of the records from the visits table anyway and the index covers only the id column. Therefore, mysql would be forced to scan through most of the records of the visits table anyway to return the data, so there is not much more to gain by using the index.
3. Index on the fields on the other side of the join. You do not mention if `labs.visit_id` field is indexed. If it is not, then again there is less to be gained from using the pk of the visits table.

The speed of producing the results does not depend on the indexes used, it also depends of the size of the resultset (both record and field count), mysql configuration, and the overall performance of the underlying system. Nevertheless,  if you believe that mysql should use the pk of the visits table, then use an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) in the query to emphasise that the index should be used. You can check with `explain` if mysql was influenced by the index hint.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. 1.Vitals table is large. 2. I need only id and one more field from visits table. 3. There is index for visit_id in lab table. 
Same tables, same structure, almost same no of rows works efficiently in another environment.  Could be related some mysql configuration?

Comment: 2. Then select only those 2 fields, not every field. 3. If the 2 tables have almost the same number of rows, then probably that's the explanation. See my 2nd point about MySQL having to retrieve most of the records from the visits table. You also say it works efficiently in another environment. Run an explain in the other environment as well. If mysql uses the pk there, then try the suggested index hint. I cannot possibly tell you if the performance difference is related to a MySQL setting or not, since I know nothing about the MySQL configuration or the server. Try the index hint first.